# Test that stops at first fail when used with map

Tags: r, purrr, testthat

I am pretty sure that this:

```
test_that("", {
  Parameters <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  test_map <- function(Parameter){
    expect_equal(Parameter,
                 2)
}
  map(Parameters, test_map)
})
```

resulted in 4 failed and 1 passed test in the past.
However it seems like since recently this doesnt work anymore and exits immediatly at the first failed test.
Is there a way around this? Possibly connected to the new reporters?

Comment: Instead of `purrr::map(Parameters, test_map)`, you can use `Map(test_map, Parameters)`

Comment: You might also be interested in the package [patrick](https://github.com/google/patrick)

Comment: which `testthat` version are you using? Works fine with `3.1.4`

Comment: @Waldi version 3.1.4 as well. Super wierd.

Comment: bretauv's `Map(..)` for me produces four complete backtraces/failures (`testthat_3.1.7`, R-4.2.3). I think I'm missing another point though ... unless you're using `testthat` for something else, isn't it sufficient to know that not all tests passed? Generally, CI/CD tools that I work with are all-or-nothing. (Yes, it might be nice if `purrr` didn't confound things by cavorting somehow with `rlang` on hiding errors, but ... it still fails.)

Comment: Adding the [tag:purrr] tag since in my run of this, the behavior changes in the presence of `purrr`.

Comment: @r2evans you are right, now that I have tried it again, ```Map(..)``` does give me the complete backtraces and passes as well. So the change was not related at all to ```testthat``` but might be linked to the ```purr 1.0.0 ``` release.

Comment: @bretauv could you post your solution as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Map()` instead of `purrr::map()`:

```r
library(testthat)

test_that("", {
  Parameters <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  test_map <- function(Parameter){
    expect_equal(Parameter,
                 2)
  }
  Map(test_map, Parameters)
})
#> ── Failure ('<text>:9:3'):  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> `Parameter` not equal to 2.
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> [1] 1 - 2 == -1
#> Backtrace:
#>  1. base::Map(test_map, Parameters)
#>  2. base::mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#>  3. `<fn>`(dots[[1L]][[5L]])
#>  4. testthat::expect_equal(Parameter, 2)
#> 
#> ── Failure ('<text>:9:3'):  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> `Parameter` not equal to 2.
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> [1] 3 - 2 == 1
#> Backtrace:
#>  1. base::Map(test_map, Parameters)
#>  2. base::mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#>  3. `<fn>`(dots[[1L]][[5L]])
#>  4. testthat::expect_equal(Parameter, 2)
#> 
#> ── Failure ('<text>:9:3'):  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> `Parameter` not equal to 2.
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> [1] 4 - 2 == 2
#> Backtrace:
#>  1. base::Map(test_map, Parameters)
#>  2. base::mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#>  3. `<fn>`(dots[[1L]][[5L]])
#>  4. testthat::expect_equal(Parameter, 2)
#> 
#> ── Failure ('<text>:9:3'):  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> `Parameter` not equal to 2.
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> [1] 5 - 2 == 3
#> Backtrace:
#>  1. base::Map(test_map, Parameters)
#>  2. base::mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#>  3. `<fn>`(dots[[1L]][[5L]])
#>  4. testthat::expect_equal(Parameter, 2)
#> Error in `reporter$stop_if_needed()`:
#> ! Test failed
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. └─testthat::test_that(...)
#>   2.   └─withr (local) `<fn>`(`<env>`)
#>   3.     ├─base::tryCatch(...)
#>   4.     │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>   5.     │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>   6.     │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>   7.     └─base::eval(handler$expr, handler$envir)
#>   8.       └─base::eval(handler$expr, handler$envir)
#>   9.         └─reporter$stop_if_needed()
#>  10.           └─rlang::abort("Test failed")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>